# No Library name in URL - Replaced with URL of site

Tags: 2013, document-library, url

Today I was confronted with an issue I have not seen before:

We have a SharePoint 2013 farm with 2 WFE and 2 APP servers. In one of the Site Collections the default Shared Documents library shows the following behavior:

The URL to a file or folder in that library or the library itself (from within Site Contents) has changed.
It seems that in the link to a document/folder/library, the name of the library is being replaced with the URL of the site (minus the special characters):

Example for the library:
Normally it would be: http://intranet.com/team/sites/SiteName/Forms/AllItems.aspx 
Now it is: http://intranet.com/team/sites/sitename/httpintranet.comteamsitesSiteName/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Example for a file:
Normally it would be: http://intranet.com/team/sites/SiteName/LibraryName/Document.xlsx 
Now it is: http://intranet.com/team/sites/SiteName/httpintranet.comteamsitesSiteName/Document.xlsx

Example for a file in a folder:
Normally it would be: http://intranet.com/team/sites/SiteName/LibraryName/Folder/Document.xlsx

Now it is: http://intranet.com/team/sites/SiteName/httpintranet.comteamsitesSiteName/Folder/Document.xlsx

This only occurs to this one document library in that one Site Collection. All other lists and libraries in that site remain unaffected by this.

How can this be reverted? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did this just happened? Sounds like someone might have changed something either through file explorer, SharePoint Designer or even PowerShell.

Comment: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/03/how-to-change-list-library-url-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: sigh...sometimes it's the simple things you don't think about. Feel free to add your comment as an answer so I can give it an 'Up' and mark it as correct :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like someone might have changed something either through file explorer, SharePoint Designer or even PowerShell.

It should be fairly simple to change it back by using any of the above options. PowerShell is probably the most quickest/efficient way.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#Web URL where the target list lives
$WebURL = "https://sharepoint.crescent.com/"
#List Name
$ListName = "ExternalProjects"
 
#Get the Web List and Library objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $web.Lists[$ListName]   
 
#Change the URL from "ExternalProjects" to "Projects"
$List.RootFolder.MoveTo("Projects")
```

[How to Change URL of the SharePoint List or Library?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/03/how-to-change-list-library-url-in-sharepoint.html)